# How can I get one record from same multiple records?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Hi I have written a query which need to show the data in drop down box. Let me share my query what i written

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt_seq_report.
       FIELD tt_seq_report.neutral_part_obj            AS DECIMAL
       FIELD tt_seq_report.patt_id                     AS CHARACTER
       FIELD tt_seq_report.npai_info2                  AS CHARACTER.

    EMPTY TEMP-TABLE tt_seq_report.

    FOR EACH gdmf_neutral_part NO-LOCK :
        FIND FIRST gdcf_part_type WHERE gdcf_part_type.part_type_obj EQ gdmf_neutral_part.part_type_obj NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
        CREATE tt_seq_report.
        ASSIGN
        tt_seq_report.neutral_part_obj          = gdmf_neutral_part.neutral_part_obj 
        tt_seq_report.patt_id                   = gdcf_part_type.patt_id WHEN AVAILABLE gdcf_part_type 
        tt_seq_report.npai_info2                = gdmf_neutral_part.npai_info2.


    END. 

/* Written in window main block */

    FOR EACH tt_seq_report NO-LOCK :
        coCombo-2:ADD-LAST(tt_seq_report.patt_id).
    END.    

    FOR EACH tt_seq_report NO-LOCK :
        coCombo-3:ADD-LAST(tt_seq_report.npai_info2).
    END.
/*
If you see tt_seq_report.patt_id and tt_seq_report.npai_info2 data  is
i.e tt_seq_report.patt_id    -BFA 
    tt_seq_report.npai_info2 -23 
    tt_seq_report.patt_id    -BFA (same id)
    tt_seq_report.npai_info2 -24
    tt_seq_report.patt_id    -SS
    tt_seq_report.npai_info2 -23 
    tt_seq_report.patt_id    -SS  (same id)
    tt_seq_report.npai_info2 -24
    tt_seq_report.patt_id    -ABS
    tt_seq_report.npai_info2 -23 
    tt_seq_report.patt_id    -ABS (same id)
    tt_seq_report.npai_info2 -24
and so on. 
*/
```

So here tt_seq_report.patt_id is same for one set of records but tt_seq_report.npai_info2 is will not be same for every records. I could use where condition if there is tt_seq_report.patt_id is BFA,SS,ABS only but it has many.

If I run this window then i can get multiple same tt_seq_report.patt_id in drop down box.

i.e once we select drop down box the showing records like below
CustID(label Name for dropbox)    Value(label Name for dropbox)

BFA                               23
BFA                               24
SS                                23
SS                                24
ABS                               23
ABS                               24

But My expected output should be

CustID(label Name for dropbox)    Value(label Name for dropbox)

BFA                               23
                                  24

SS                                23
                                  24

ABS                               23
                                  24

Please help this case. Thank you.

Comment: May I get answer for my questions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
FOR EACH tt_seq_report NO-LOCK :
    If lookup(tt_seq_report.patt_id, ccombo2:list-items) = 0 then
        coCombo-2:ADD-LAST(tt_seq_report.patt_id).
END.
```

I don't know your scope and I'm doing this on mobile, so you might need to change it to list-items in frame {&frame-name) or your real frame name, if it's not {&frame-name}.

EDIT: Since you asked for an alternative, you can also do this:

```
FOR EACH tt_seq_report NO-LOCK 
         BREAK BY tt_seq_report.patt_id:
    If first-of(tt_Seq_report.patt_id) then
        coCombo-2:ADD-LAST(tt_seq_report.patt_id).
END.
```

Comment: I executed this code and no value populated.Could you pls tell me the other way?

Comment: Are you sure you have data in tt_seq_report when you're doing this? I just tested it here and it works.
Put this message before the FOR EACH: message temp-table tt_seq_report:has-records view-as alert-box.
What does the message say?

Comment: Oh, and you can put both combo populations in the same for each. No need to do it twice.

Comment: Thank you so much sir..its working like lightening speed.